# Partition (segregate) by time period span in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My question is to segregate data from time information in SQL

I have transaction data for trams. Something like this

```
DateTime
2018-04-03T08:06:04
2018-04-03T08:07:27
2018-04-03T08:18:18
2018-04-03T10:08:27
2018-04-03T10:22:24
2018-04-03T12:08:50
2018-04-03T12:24:49
2018-04-03T12:24:51
```

This is the customer *tap on* information for specific tram on specific day. This contains 3 journey of the same tram

1. First Journey
   first transaction is at 8:06, second at 8:07 and third at 8:18
2. Second Journey
   first transaction is at 10:08, second at 10:22
3. Third Journey
   first transaction is at 12:08, second at 12:24 and third at 24:24

How can I rank them as 3 different journeys so desired result will be like this

```
Rank    DateTime
1   2018-04-03T08:06:04
1   2018-04-03T08:07:27
1   2018-04-03T08:18:18
2   2018-04-03T10:08:27
2   2018-04-03T10:22:24
3   2018-04-03T12:08:50
3   2018-04-03T12:24:49
3   2018-04-03T12:24:51
```

I tried by adding +- 40 mins to time and all transactions coming in the range will be one unique journey. But couldn't succeed.

Comment: what is the logic of ranking 1,2,3 and where is the other parameter of time

Comment: The tram starts at 8:06 AM from stop 1, goes to stop 15 at 8:18 AM then take full journey with 30 more stops, and comes to same stop 1 at around 10 AM. 
Start again at 10:08 AM from stop 1, goes to stop 16 at 10:22. Thus cycle continues for whole day.

Comment: so is it hard coded 8 to <10 will be rank 1 and 10 to <12 rank 2 ...

Comment: No, It is dynamic. A single tram can take 5 up-down routes. So there will be 5 unique rank based on time difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT dt, 1 + SUM(start) OVER(ORDER BY dt) journey 
FROM (
  SELECT dt, IF(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(dt, LAG(dt) OVER(ORDER BY dt), MINUTE) > 40, 1, 0) start
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data from  your question as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2018-04-03T08:06:04' dt UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-04-03T08:07:27' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-04-03T08:18:18' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-04-03T10:08:27' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-04-03T10:22:24' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-04-03T12:08:50' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-04-03T12:24:49' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-04-03T12:24:51' 
)
SELECT dt, 1 + SUM(start) OVER(ORDER BY dt) journey 
FROM (
  SELECT dt, IF(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(dt, LAG(dt) OVER(ORDER BY dt), MINUTE) > 40, 1, 0) start
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
-- ORDER BY dt
```

with result

```
Row dt                          journey  
1   2018-04-03 08:06:04 UTC     1    
2   2018-04-03 08:07:27 UTC     1    
3   2018-04-03 08:18:18 UTC     1    
4   2018-04-03 10:08:27 UTC     2    
5   2018-04-03 10:22:24 UTC     2    
6   2018-04-03 12:08:50 UTC     3    
7   2018-04-03 12:24:49 UTC     3    
8   2018-04-03 12:24:51 UTC     3
```

Note: I derived logic from below statement in your question

> I tried by adding +- 40 mins to time and all transactions coming in the range will be one unique journey

A liiiittle less verbose version:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT dt, 1 + COUNTIF(start) OVER(ORDER BY dt) journey 
FROM (
  SELECT dt, (TIMESTAMP_DIFF(dt, LAG(dt) OVER(ORDER BY dt), MINUTE) > 40) start
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
ORDER BY dt
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much :)
I wasn't aware of any such logic in bigquery/SQL.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant . . . I was actually going to suggest your less verbose version (actually a slight variation) but then I saw that you already had it.